# Cannot retrieve data from Parse User

Tags: facebook, parse-platform, unity-game-engine

Parse Data Example
[image: Parse Data Example]

As you can see in the image above, I have Users with scores for levels stored in ParseUsers.

My problem is, when I have the ParseUser logged in on my app and attempt to check if the User ContainsKey("ScoreLevel1"), it is returning false.

I'm assuming I'm just missing something quite obvious or something, but is there something extra that I have to do to retrieve this data?

I'm trying to do a friends based leaderboard system but with this not working, it isn't really possible.

The keys that the user apparently does contain are:

- username
- sessionToken
- authData
- Name
- CurrentHighestLevel

Name and CurrentHighestLevel are two custom values that I have put in, and I can retrieve them, I just can't retrieve the scores?

EDIT: Okay, I know this isn't exactly a proper solution to the problem I posted, which is why I didn't post this as an answer, but I tried using the REST API and it fully retrieves everything I need. I am switching over away from Unity's Parse SDK and just using the REST API from now on as it seems to work better.

Comment: Could you give as more information about your exact code? Also, which SDK are you using? (iOS, Java, ...?)

Comment: Each ParseObject contains key-value pairs of JSON-compatible data. This data is schemaless, which means that you don't need to specify ahead of time what keys exist on each ParseObject. There might be a mismatch between what you hold locally and what you have on the server in your user object. Can you give more details ?

Comment: @EricSchanet I am using the Unity SDK. The information is pretty much just a copy of what is shown in their developer guides [here](https://parse.com/docs/unity/guide#users-querying). It just seems weird because I have used the check to initially upload the data where it SHOULD be showing as false, but now that the data is up there, it is STILL showing false. What details do you want/need?

Comment: Just found out that the data CAN be retrieved when running in the Unity Editor, but doesn't work when I build out to the iOS device. No difference in the code